# Retrieve sorted data based on one numeric column in SQLITE

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite, system.data.sqlite, sqlite-net

I have a table like attached image in SQLITE database.

[image: Sqlite table]

I am trying to retrieve sorted data based on SUM(freight) column. For this i have used the below query.

**SELECT ShipCountry
FROM CountryDetails
GROUP BY ShipCountry
ORDER BY SUM(freight) ASC**
When i run this i am getting result like below.

[image: Sqlite result]

If i run the below query i am getting result like below. It's fine.

**SELECT ShipCountry, ShipCity
FROM CountryDetails
GROUP BY ShipCountry, ShipCity
ORDER BY SUM(Freight), ShipCity ASC**

[image: Result]

Instead of this i need a result like below. In order by clause SUM(Freight) should consider only ShipCountry. It should not consider both ShipCountry and ShipCity. My Expected result is

[image: Tableau result]

How to achieve this result through SQLITE query?

in SQL we can achieve like below query.

**Select ShipCountry, ShipCity from Countrydetails group by ShipCountry, ShipCity Order by SUM(SUM(freight)) over(partition by ShipCountry), Shipcity Asc.**

We need equivalent query like this in Sqlite.

Comment: Seattle in Poland?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery to find the frieght sum for each country, then order using only this country level sum:

```
SELECT
    cd1.ShipCountry,
    cd1.ShipCity
FROM Countrydetails cd1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ShipCountry, SUM(freight) AS freight_sum
    FROM Countrydetails
    GROUP BY ShipCountry
) cd2
    ON cd1.ShipCountry = cd2.ShipCountry
ORDER BY
    cd1.freight_sum,
    cd1.ShipCountry,    -- needed in case two countries happen to have the same sum
    cd1.ShipCity
```

We could add another sort level for the `frieght` of each city, to order within a given country.  But your expected output does not imply that you want this.

Comment: Thanks. after did minor change in Order by clause it works great. 
ORDER By
cd2.freight_sum
cd1.ShipCountry
cd1.ShipCity